# How can I fix the ‘adddoc’ line on my Cloud Firestore code so the form on my HTML webpage successfully sends data to Firestore?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I was trying to make a HTML for which saves the response onto Firebase.

However, when it got to the `adddoc` line, the page appears to refresh only with nothing sent over.

Here is my code, i have used firefox's debugging tool to find out which line is causing the issue.

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Initialize Cloud Firestore and get a reference to the service
const db = getFirestore(app);

document.getElementById("registration").onsubmit = async function() { submit(); };

async function submit() {
    const data = {
        name: document.getElementById("input-1").value,
        officialName: document.getElementById("input-2").value,
        universityID: document.getElementById("input-3").value,
        degree: document.getElementById("input-4").value,
        referral: document.getElementById("input-5").value,
        email: document.getElementById("input-6").value,
        phone: document.getElementById("input-7").value,
    };
    console.log(data);
    try {
        console.log("Attempting to send");
        const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), data); // The Page Refreshes here
        console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
        alert(docRef.id);
    } catch (e) {
        alert("Error adding document: ", e);
    }
};
```

The submit() function works perfectly okay when i call it alone on init, and with the data replaced with constants. However, i cant get the data from the form to send to firebase